# Positive part of a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

Call a distribution $u\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ nonnegative if for all nonnegative test functions $\varphi$, $u(\varphi)\geq0$. What is known about when do distributions have positive and negative parts, i.e. when can one find for a given $u\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$, nonnegative distributions $u^+,u^-\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ such that $u=u^+-u^-$?

Comment: I'm quite sure that $u$ has to be of order zero, and probably that is also enough.

Comment: https://books.google.se/books?id=T7vEOGGDCh4C&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=positive+distributions&source=bl&ots=t5Zi39j1qZ&sig=Eb0Enz8zHKv3vxYHXOAUrx07xgY&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSptD_7u3UAhViQJoKHV_OCD4Q6AEIaTAK#v=onepage&q=positive%20distributions&f=false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This book](https://books.google.se/books?id=T7vEOGGDCh4C&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=positive%20distributions&source=bl&ots=t5Zi39j1qZ&sig=Eb0Enz8zHKv3vxYHXOAUrx07xgY&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSptD_7u3UAhViQJoKHV_OCD4Q6AEIaTAK#v=onepage&q=positive%20distributions&f=false) says that a distribution is nonnegative if and only if it is given by a nonnegative measure. This means that the distribution ($u$ as well as $u^+$ and $u^-$) has to be of order zero. Thus, if $u = u^+ - u^-$ with $u^\pm \geq 0$ then $u$ must be the difference between two nonnegative measures and is therefore a signed measure. And since a locally finite signed measure gives a distribution, and a signed measure can be split into a positive and a negative part (by the [Hahn Decomposition Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem)), then we have an "if and only if":

A distribution $u$ can be decomposed as $u = u^+ - u^-$ with $u^\pm \geq 0$ if and only if $u(f) = \int f(x) \, d\mu(x)$ for some locally finite measure $\mu$.

Comment: Indeed. Just to expand slightly on the point: the obvious notion of "positivity" of a distribution turns out _not_ to be what we might think, e.g., not well related to positivity of a locally integrable function that more-or-less gives the distribution. This is immediately the case with meromorphic continuation of distributions such as (integration against) $|x|^s$ (as in Hadamard's finie-partie idea, explicated by Riesz). I think it's better not to think to depend on what appears to be "positivity" of distributions.

Comment: Not every nonnegative distribution is given by a nonnegative function, but every nonnegative and locally integrable function gives a nonnegative distribution. And every nonnegative distribution can be approximated by a nonnegative function by $u \approx u * \eta_\epsilon$, where $\eta_\epsilon$ is a nonnegative approximation to the identity, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Approximations_to_the_identity